# SQL AVG Alias with CASE

Tags: sql, alias

I am trying to run this query, but facing an unknown column error for Average:

```
SELECT CAST(AVG(Lesson_CLass.T_Points) AS Decimal (10,0)) AS Average,
       CASE WHEN Lesson_CLass.T_Points = Average THEN 'On Target'
            WHEN Lesson_CLass.T_Points < Average THEN 'Above Target'
            ELSE 'Below Target'
       END AS Progress
FROM Lesson_CLass
```

I am unsure as to why the Alias is unknown?

Comment: The column alias isn't available in the same SELECT clause as it's defined.

Comment: You cannot define an alias in a select clause and use this alias in the same select clause.

Comment: ^this, plus since you are using an aggregation function, you should be grouping by the second column ('progress')

Comment: Yep, I was about to say something like this. The query is invalid. It is written to return one single row with an aggregation value (`AVG(...)` over all rows in the table. And at the same time it shall return every row with a progess evaluated from its `T_Points`. This is of course not possible.

Comment: I suppose you want to use the analytic function `AVG OVER` instead. And you probably want to select other columns, too, to so as to see *what* is on target or above it. What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The column alias isn't available in the same `SELECT` clause as it's defined.

With a *derived table*, you can use the alias in the `case` *expression*:

```
SELECT Average,
       CASE WHEN T_Points = Average THEN 'On Target'
            WHEN T_Points < Average THEN 'Above Target'
            ELSE 'Below Target'
       END AS Progress
FROM
(
    SELECT Lesson_CLass.T_Points,
           CAST(AVG(Lesson_CLass.T_Points) AS Decimal (10,0)) AS Average
    FROM Lesson_CLass
) dt
```

Comment: This gives me Unknown column 'Lesson_CLass.T_Points' in 'field list'?

Comment: @PythonHelp. oops. Now edited.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing here: You are probably trying to compare single rows with the overall average value.

### The classic way with a subquery for the total average:

```
select
  lc.*,
  av.avg_t_points,
  case 
    when lc.t_points = av.avg_t_points then 'On Target'
    when lc.t_points < av.avg_t_points then 'Above Target'
    else 'Below Target'
  end as progress
from lesson_class lc
cross join
(
  select avg(t_points) as avg_tpoints
  from lesson_class
) as av;
```

### The modern way with an analytic function for the total average:

```
select
  with_avg.*,
  case 
    when t_points = avg_t_points then 'On Target'
    when t_points < avg_t_points then 'Above Target'
    else 'Below Target'
  end as progress
from 
(
  select lc.*, avg(t_points) over () as avg_tpoints
  from lesson_class
) with_avg;
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you, modern way worked for me!

Comment: How do I group by progress?

Comment: Like this: `select progress, count(*) from ( <above query> ) categorized group by progress`?